# (Vagrant | VirtualBox) 127.0.0.1:4567 is not displaying my web page

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I'm currently using Vagrant and have provisioned a box with the following (provision using a script):

***script.sh***:

```
#INSTALL APACHE
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2

#INSTALL MySQL
sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql

#ACTIVATE MySQL
sudo mysql_install_db

#MySQL Setup
sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation

#INSTALL PHP
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt

#ADD PHP TO DIRECTORY INDEX
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf
```

and I have a ***Vagrantfile*** setup as follows:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "script.sh"


# config.vm.box_check_update = false


config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 4567


config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"


# config.vm.network "public_network"


config.vm.synced_folder "C:\Vagrant", "/Vagrant"


config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  vb.gui = true
  vb.memory = "1024"

#config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  end
end
```

I have created the following directory in the VM  (***/Vagrant***) and hold all my website files within a directory on my host machine (Windows) called (***C:\Vagrant***).

Now, as far as i'm aware this really shouldn't be too complicated. I provision the machine with Apache to deal with requests. I forward the correct port from the host (4567) to the guest's web port (80).

I then sync the folders to move the web files onto the VM using: 
***config.vm.synced_folder "C:\Vagrant", "/Vagrant"***

Where the host's folder is ***C:\Vagrant*** (which is 100% categoric - i'd sell my own mother down the river for a chocolate bar - valid location) and the VM folder is ***/Vagrant*** where I used ***mkdir /Vagrant*** to create the directory and ***$ ls*** to confirm that it has indeed been created.

***The Error***:

When I attempt to run ***vagrant up***, I get thrown the following error:

***the host path of the shared folder is missing: C:Vagrant *** - now I seem to think this is because it is escaping the backslash and so it will always be an invalid location. But surely, that makes it impossible to sync to a Windows file directory system.

Would anybody be able to lend me a hand? As to be honest, even after this issue is resolved - I still won't be able to view the test.html page I have created for one reason or another. But at least this is a step in the right direction.

Kind regards, 
Tom

Comment: did you try using `C:\\Vargrant` ? You may even need (in my experience) up to 5 `'\'` chars to get the correct quoting. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Shellter, I found that C:/Vagrant seems to work. To be honest im not looking for a quick work around. I genuinely want to know what is causing this issue. As it seems like the host folder that doesnt exist .. works (C:/Vagrant) and the host folder that is actually in existence (C:\Vagrant) is unable to be found. This seems ludicrous !

Edit: Just to want to add, that despite C:/Vagrant allowing the VM to boot .. I still cant work out how to load my test.html page.

Comment: For the record, I've now uninstalled this tool .. 100% a complete waste of time. I'd rather try to configure a Gerbil to host my website.

Comment: Sorry to hear it and I feel your pain. Did you look for a Vagrant devs support forum would be my only final offer for help (I don't have any experience with Vagrant, just linux/ubuntu and shells. AND my sense from reading many similar Qs here on S.O. is that VirtualBox et.al. are a separate can of worms. Good luck getting your project back on track!

Comment: Yeah thanks very much for your support Shellter, I have just decided to host the site on my local machine. I'm not supporting multiple client portfolios - so the need to separate work through VMs isnt needed at this stage. It was purely for the setup of a consistent work environment. 

All the best :)